# Converting a simple regex line from perl to python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to convert this line from Perl to python:

```
$line =~ s/$alwayssep/ $& /g;
```

Any ideas how this might be done in python?

Comment: As most of us are here for Python, could you explain what this would normally do in Perl.

Comment: @Malik this interprets the contents of the variable `$alwayssep` as a regex pattern, and substitutes all matches of this pattern in the variable `$line` with *<space><matched string><space>*.

Comment: @Lucas : yes, exactly, only with the small detail of that it actually only changes the last matched pattern. meaning something like \1 but for the last match and not the 1st one

Comment: @AbrahamLincool that `g` modifier tells me otherwise. I'm pretty sure this line substitutes all matches.

Comment: @Lucas so, correct me if I am wrong, you are suggesting that it would be absolutely alright if we used the python \1 switch? right?

Comment: In other words, Malik's answer to the question is totally correct, right?

Comment: @Abraham, nope I didn't say that. He used the equivalent of `$1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, do the following where `alwayssep` is the expression and `line` is the passed string:

```
line = re.sub(alwayssep, r' \g<0> ', line)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, but would you mind telling me why you have substituted \1 for $& here? cause in my head \1 is only a replacement for Perl's $1.

Comment: I mean the line you have written seems to be a python equivalent for Perl's: $line =~ s/$alwayssep/ $1 /s;

Comment: Maybe you should use `\g<0>` instead of `\1` :-)

Comment: *"if the whole pattern is grouped"* indeed. I don't know Python but I've found the following in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub): *The backreference `\g<0>` substitutes in the entire substring matched by the RE."*

Comment: @Malik : Yes I want to mark it as answered, but how can I?

Answer (score 1):

My [Pythonizer](https://github.com/snoopyjc/pythonizer) converts that to this:

```
line = re.sub(re.compile(alwayssep),r' \g<0> ',line,count=0)
```